# Unable to get a single linebreak while sending email through Sendgrid

Tags: python, django, email

I'm using `django.core.mail` to send email. I want to achieve a single linebreak at some points in the email, as shown here:

```
Line 1
Line 2

Line 3
Line 4
```

I tried doing this using `\n` after `Line 1` and `Line 3`, and `\n\n` after `Line 2` and `Line 4`.

When I send the email, it is received like this:

```
Line 1 Line 2

Line 3 Line 4
```

As per recommendations on other StackOverflow answers, I tried using the `django.template.loader.render_to_string` method to generate the appropriate string from a file, but it generates a string with the `\n` in the exact places where I put them, and so on sending the email it produces the same undesired result.

When I print the string to stdout it appears as desired.

In summary, the `\n\n` are working but the `\n` are getting converted to spaces while sending email through Django's `send_mail`. How can this be solved? Please note that this question is regarding plaintext emails, not HTML ones.

EDIT: Source, as requested in the comments:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail(
    'Test subject',
    'Line 1\nLine 2\n\nLine 3\nLine 4\n\n',
    'noreply@test.com',
    ['myemail@gmail.com'],
)
```

Sent using SMTP via SendGrid, as is specified in my `settings.py` file:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you are using to send the email?

Comment: @solarissmoke posted

Comment: This works just fine for me (also using Sendgrid) - resulting email is exactly like the desired result you have posted. Maybe your mail client isn't rendering it properly? Have you inspected the source of the received email?

Comment: @solarissmoke I checked using Gmail and RoundCube, it looks like there are `<p> .. </p>` tags around everything which I separated using `\n\n`. The desired result is a `<br>` replacing all `\n`, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening because you're using Sendgrid, which [in some cases will convert your plain text messages to HTML](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Format_Content/plain_text_emails_converted_to_html.html). Most likely you have configured it to do open/click tracking and it cannot do these in plain text, so it converts your message to HTML.

The link above offers these solutions:

> 1. You can turn off the filters causing the conversion from plain text to HTML.
> 2. If you start each line with a space, this will add a “preformatted” tag around the line.
> 3. You can separate new sentences with double newlines, which will add a "paragraph" tag around the sentence.
> 4. You can convert your message to HTML, bypassing our need to convert it altogether
> 5. To disable conversion globally, visit Mail Settings --> Plain Content and enabled the suppression.

Comment: The reason I was using plaintext in the first place (inside a multi-part email) is to account for clients which can't handle HTML. I should have picked up on HTML appearing inside the email body. Thanks a lot!